# Recreate a fragment from scratch or use the backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have to develop a questionnaire app that shows a sequence of 8 different screen layouts, each screen with different data. The particular sequence depends on the user's previous responses. So it might go something like this:

A > B > B > B > C > B > B > D > D > D > D > D > D > D > D > D > E > F > F > F > F > B > B > G > F > F> etc

The sequence of questions might be as long as 500 questions (according to the requirements). When the back button is pressed, some of these screens should be skipped (for example you might not show some of the F or some of the D).

I'm new to android and perhaps didn't make the best choices: I have 1 activity for the questionnaire and multiple fragments (A, B, C, D, etc) that are presented consecutively according to the questionnaire's logic and the user's previous replies. Going back is done with the use of the backstack. There have been a lot of problems with going back and then again forward (keeping the correct state/ keeping the correct data in the fragment / memory issues etc).

At this point the app has gotten so convoluted and buggy that I'm considering perhaps scrapping the backstack. Maybe I could just put the sequence of fragments in the database as I go forward (meaning just the type of fragment and a few associated ids), then retrieve the relevant data from the db and recreate the previous fragment from scratch in the onBackPressed method if the back button is pressed. It seems cleaner and perhaps less prone to unexpected behaviors (?) especially since i'm inexperienced in android.

Is this an acceptable solution? How would creating the fragment each time affect memory performance and cpu performance? What would be the disadvantages or advantages of this approach? 
What in your opinion would be the best architecture for this particular app?

Comment: Does any A for example contain the same as any other A, or is their Content dependant from the previous Fragments?

Comment: Each A fragment contains different texts & images, that are initially retrieved from the database depending on the question's ID. Same with B, C etc Also when you're going either back or forward, to an already answered question, then the previous user response ought to be visible.

Comment: If the Fragment is already added and not removed, and you override back to create that Fragment again without having previously removed it, you will run into oddities. Unfortunately I'm not sure when you actually need to skip some Ds and Fs.

Comment: Replace is used for all fragments, so as I understand it the current fragment is removed before the next fragment being added. My confusion is more regarding architecture than anything else. The bugs can be resolved with some work but I wonder if there is an alternative better way to deal with this very complicated sequence of fragments.